# Kafka Streamer: Issue with user defined 'Serdes'

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am using Confluent-3.2.1 as a Kafka streamer. I am trying to aggregate my `KGroupedStream<String, MyClass1>` into `KTable<Windowed<String>,MsgAggr>`. While using aggregation, I am also using `TimeWindows.of(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(5))`.  I am using user defined "Serdes" as an argument to aggregation. The code for User define "Serdes" is,

```java
Map<String, Object> serdeProps = new HashMap<>();

final Serializer<MsgAggr> pageViewSerializer = new JsonPOJOSerializer<>();
serdeProps.put("JsonPOJOClass", MsgAggr.class);
pageViewSerializer.configure(serdeProps, false);

final Deserializer<MsgAggr> pageViewDeserializer = new JsonPOJODeserializer<>();
serdeProps.put("JsonPOJOClass", MsgAggr.class);
pageViewDeserializer.configure(serdeProps, false);

final Serde<MsgAggr> pageViewSerde = Serdes.serdeFrom(pageViewSerializer, pageViewDeserializer);`
```

Code for Streaming is

```java
KGroupedStream<String, MyClass1> msg_grp = message
            .groupByKey();  
KTable<Windowed<String>,MsgAggr> msg_win = msg_grp
            //.reduce(new Reduced(), arg1, arg2);
            .aggregate(new Init(), 
                    new Aggr(), 
                    TimeWindows.of(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(5)), 
                    pageViewSerde, 
                    "MySample_out");
```

When I run the code I got the errors:

```
[2017-05-23 18:16:45,648] ERROR stream-thread [StreamThread-1] Streams application error during processing:  (org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread:249)
java.lang.ClassCastException: my.kafka.strm.MyClass1 cannot be cast to java.lang.String
at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer.serialize(StringSerializer.java:24)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.send(RecordCollectorImpl.java:64)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SinkNode.process(SinkNode.java:82)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:202)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamFilter$KStreamFilterProcessor.process(KStreamFilter.java:44)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:82)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:202)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamMap$KStreamMapProcessor.process(KStreamMap.java:43)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:82)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:202)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:66)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:180)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:436)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:242)
Exception in thread "StreamThread-1" java.lang.ClassCastException: my.kafka.strm.MyClass1 cannot be cast to java.lang.String
at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer.serialize(StringSerializer.java:24)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.send(RecordCollectorImpl.java:64)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SinkNode.process(SinkNode.java:82)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:202)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamFilter$KStreamFilterProcessor.process(KStreamFilter.java:44)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:82)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:202)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamMap$KStreamMapProcessor.process(KStreamMap.java:43)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:82)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:202)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:66)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:180)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:436)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:242)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with `message.groupByKey();`. Its using the String Serde for your custom class `MyClass1`. Please implement custom Serializer and deserializer for `MyClass1` and use the same in the overloaded version of `groupByKey` - https://kafka.apache.org/0102/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html#groupByKey(org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serde,%20org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serde)

Comment: One more question is about event-time window processing. Inside the aggregate I am using TimeWindow. Also I am extracting the time stamp from stream using `streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.TIMESTAMP_EXTRACTOR_CLASS_CONFIG, MyEventTimeExtractor.class);`  I want to use the time which is a part of the message to control the window aggregation.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: The `MyEventTimeExtractor` implementation can use the `ConsumerRecord#timestamp` method to get the event timestamp

Comment: If you want to use the record embedded timestamp from Kafka, there are already 3 pre-defined extractors you could use: http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide.html#streams-developer-guide-timestamp-extractor Thus I am not sure if it's required to implement your own extractor for this case.

Comment: If you are want to extract a timestamp from key or record, just access the date from the given `ConsumerRecord` via `#key()` and/or `#value()`